# How to do complicate ORDER BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Is there any way to customize `ORDER BY` in MySQL? DESC and ASC are too simple to do complete ordering.

I want to give a weight to each field and calculate a sum to order.

For example,I have a table containing fields A, B and C. A's weight is 2, B's is 1 and C's is 3. So the result should be ORDER BY 2*A+B+3*C DESC/ASC. How can I do this?

Comment: You can add the expression in your select and order by that new field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT a, b, c, (2*a+b+3*c) combined_weighting FROM table ORDER BY combined_weighting DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ORDER BY is used for returning data in a certain order once the db server gives the data back to the stream.  You are trying to do a complex formula on the ORDER BY that should be considered in your GROUP BY clause AND quite possible TEMP tables